# Is there any reason why I cannot use route53 traffic flow to send traffic to a domain I don't have control over?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I have been asked by a small business to setup some load balancing for them. One server is based in Sydney, the other in London.

I am thinking of using Amazon's Route53 traffic flow offering. The thing is they do not want to delegate the domain to my control. They are happy however for me to create another domain  which I would have control of.

Is there any reason why I couldn't setup that new Domains NS records to point to AWS. Then load balance traffic requests coming to that new domain to the appropriate original domain?

I'm guessing any health checks would have to be against the original domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from doing that as long as the new domain is a public hosted zone in R53 and you are using R53 for the NS.

In R53 you will need to use a CNAME resource record type to point to the original domain, and the health checks associated will need to be for the original domain as you say.